# Passing Data From C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, sockets

I am looking into developing a C# app which needs to be called from a legacy unmanaged C++ app. The C# app will create a Winforms or WPF window (still researching which to go with) which has a third party control in it. First of all, I looked into using a C++/CLR wrapper class to call it and then COM Interop. Both of these methods were fine until the third party control was added to the form. The company who produce this control stated that they would not support their product when called from unmanaged C++.

I am now considering alternatives where the C# app is a standalone app which I can then pass data from the C++ app possibly through Sockets or similar.

I was wondering if anyone could recommend the best way to do this. I have considered sockets or memory mapped files. I am not sure what is the best method or if there is a better one.

Comment: Using two separate processes is the way to go, since that will be easier than starting from native C++ and adding in managed UI which gives lots of strange headaches, even though it's possible.  So you're best bet is to do "IPC between C++ and C#", google that search string, there are many possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience is far more easy to call c++ code from c# through c++/CLI wrappers than the other way around. I would try to write an active requester from the C# app that would ask for the information to the c++ code through a c++/CLI wrapper.

It doesn't matter who consumes the data or who is responsible for producing the data. It's just a matter of structuring the calls

**c++ code**

```
bool do_you_have_something_for_me();
void get_data_from_cpp_code(HugeStructure &response);
```

**c++/CLI code**

```
ref class Wrapper
{

   public bool waitForRequestCppCode()
   {
       if(do_you_have_something_for_me())
       {
          //call get_data_from_cpp_code and put the result in a nice .NET class
          return true;
       }
       else return false;
   }
}
```

**c# code**

```
while(!waitForRequestCppCode())
{
   //Do C# app stuff
}
//access the info from the wrapper and act, rinse and repeat
```

This is just a very rough code, probably with a lot of mistakes, just to prove a point.

Comment: Not an option for this application hence why I asked how to pass data from C++ to C#. There *may* be a scenario where we want to pass data both ways but C++ to C# is most important.

Comment: From what you state, you have access to both c++ and the C# code. It's not a matter of who consumes or produces the data, but of which end makes the calls. I'll try to go further with my answer

Comment: How would c# acquire and use data from HugeStructure &response?

Answer (score 2):

In C#, you can create a subclass of `System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent` to create a COM+ service which can be called from unmanaged code (with `CoCreateInstance`).

Look at this article for more informations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973847.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> The company who produce this control stated that they would not support their product when called from unmanaged C++.

I don't think you'll get any problems if call it from managed c++.

Comment: I do get problems as I stated in the original post. It crashes the app and the company acknowledge it is a problem and won't support using it in that way. Please could we stick to the question being asked here. Thanks very much.

Comment: Maybe, but that's one very odd control if it "detects" it's in a mixed-mode environment and crashes.  I've done a number of mixed-mode applications (managed calling native, and native calling managed, and even back-and-forth in the same program) and never encountered your problem.  Maybe try putting it in a separate application domain, and see if that calms it down so it can't "detect" its way to failure?

Comment: I am not bothering to investigate why it crashes simply because the company have said they won't support it. The control costs thousands of pounds so to use it in an unsupported way is simply commercially stupid. Any company would be crazy to use third party tools that are unsupported. Hence why we are looking into other ways of using it. The reason why the company will not support it in this way is irrelevant to us.